# CM_Get_DevNode_Property, where is DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc?

Tags: c, winapi

I want to get device descriptions, and it seems that I need to use `CM_Get_DevNode_Property` in "cfgmgr32.h". [The examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/porting-from-setupapi-to-cfgmgr32) I have found on the web are all passing the address of some constant or variable like  `&DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc` or other names that start with "DEVPKEY_". I searched the example codes to find where they are defined, but none of the examples have those thing explicitly declared or defined.

My Visual Studio code does not find that thing, and the compilation fails with a message like

> 'DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc': undeclared identifier

How do I get that variable? I have included "Windows.h" and "cfgmgr32.h" and added the Cfgmgr32.lib.

Comment: `#include <devpkey.h>`

Comment: @RbMm Thanks. Including the header made VS to recognise it, but linkage error (LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc) occurs. I think I need to add the library, but I could not find the library name by searching the web. I have tried "Devpkey.lib", but that kind of file does not seem to exist. Would you let me know the library name, too?

Comment: Found a solution for the linkage error. I need to include `<initguid.h>` BEFORE `devpkey.h`. Damn, why don't the examples mention these?

Comment: Initguid.h includes guiddef.h, which declares the DEFINE_GUID macro. Therefore, it is needed before any header related to device classes and properties.